# iPhone app crashes with no justifiable reason?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, crash

I am developing an app in which I have a table. In the table cell I have an imageview ( the images are displayed via url ) and a textview/webview. I start threads for each row to get the images in the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method ( if image is not already got ) and set the text of textview/webview from an array.

The problem arises when the images are being received and I pop the view, the application crashes giving the following message:

**bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x1a0670: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...**

Now the situation becomes more weird if I don't release the textview/webview that I added to the cell, then every thing works fine.

**Edit:** the crash does not happens when I replace textview/webview with a label

Hoping I am clear in my question. If any thing is confusing please comment. I need to resolve this.

Thanks,

Nikhil

Comment: It sounds like one of your background threads is trying to do something to the user interface, but (in general) only the primary thread should be calling any methods on user interface objects.

Comment: @Isaac : the question itself says what u said, but the edit point is much important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a huge mistake to use threads. Try to avoid using threads if you have other solutions !

In your case, just use an asynchronous NSURLConnection which will take care of downloading your image while not slowing your app ;)

Here is part of the code :

```
- (void) startDownload {
    self.activeDownload = [NSMutableData data];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:
                             [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                              [NSURL URLWithString:@"blablabla"]] delegate:self];
    self.imageConnection = conn;
    [conn release];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Download support (NSURLConnectionDelegate)

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.activeDownload appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR DOWNLOADING");
    // Clear the activeDownload property to allow later attempts
    self.activeDownload = nil;

    // Release the connection now that it's finished
    self.imageConnection = nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"FINISH DOWNLOAD");

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:self.activeDownload];
    self.activeDownload = nil;
    self.imageConnection = nil;

    //do whatever you want with your image

    [image release];
}
```